# Enable Wordpress Debug only for Admin

Tags: debug

Is it possible to enable debug alert just for admin user? there is a way by adding a secret query in URL.
But I do not want to use it. is there anyway just display debugs, for admin?

Comment: Display where, in the error log? Notification?

Comment: HTML. I mean frontend.

Comment: As an aside, an error log is a better solution, as is a debug plugin, but none are as good as a local developer environment with XDebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
if(!function_exists('display_php_error_for_admin')) {
    function display_php_error_for_admin()
    {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
        $roles = $user_meta->roles;
        if(is_array($roles)){
            if (in_array("administrator", $roles)) {
                error_reporting(0);
                @ini_set('display_errors', 0);
            } 
        }elseif ($roles == "administrator"){
            error_reporting(0);
            @ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        }

    }
}
add_action('init','display_php_error_for_admin');
```

Comment: thanks. it woks. but gets an error in `if (in_array(`  line.   `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in `

Comment: May be you are not logged in? Always check if user isn't logged in before ad unset errors if so then return before the conditional. Or simply check if(empty($roles)) { error_reporting(0); return; }

Comment: @D.JCode I add some conditional checking to it, it might work better